# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable when reading from HDFS

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I'm reading in a file from HDFS and I keep getting this error:
`TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

csv file:

```
CLAIM_NUM,BEN_ST,AGE,MEDICAL_ONLY_IND,TTL_MED_LOSS,TTL_IND_LOSS,TTL_MED_EXP,TTL_IND_EXP,BP_CD,NI_CD,legalrep,depression,cardiac,diabetes,hypertension,obesity,smoker,subabuse,arthritis,asthma,CPT_codes,D,P,NDC_codes
123456789,IL,99,1,2201.26,0,97.16,0,31,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,NA,8409~71941,NA,NA
987654321,AL,98,1,568.12,0,20.82,0,42,52,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,NA,7242~8472~E9273,NA,NA
```

My code:

```
with hdfs.open("/user/ras.csv") as f: 
    reader = f.read()
    
    for i, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
        root = ET.Element('cbcalc')
        icdNode = ET.SubElement(root, "icdcodes")
        
        for code in row['D'].split('~'):
            ET.SubElement(icdNode, "code").text = code
        ET.SubElement(root, "clientid").text = row['CLAIM_NUM']
        ET.SubElement(root, "state").text = row['BEN_ST']
        ET.SubElement(root, "country").text = "US"  
        ET.SubElement(root, "age").text = row['AGE']
        ET.SubElement(root, "jobclass").text = "1" 
        ET.SubElement(root, "fulloutput").text ="Y"
        
        cfNode = ET.SubElement(root, "cfactors")
        for k in ['legalrep', 'depression', 'diabetes',
                 'hypertension', 'obesity', 'smoker', 'subabuse']:
            ET.SubElement(cfNode, k.lower()).text = str(row[k])
        
        psNode = ET.SubElement(root, "prosummary")
        
        psicdNode = ET.SubElement(psNode, "icd")
        for code in row['P'].split('~'):
            ET.SubElement(psNode, "code").text = code
            
        psndcNode = ET.SubElement(psNode, "ndc")
        for code in row['NDC_codes'].split('~'):
            ET.SubElement(psNode, "code").text = code 

        cptNode = ET.SubElement(psNode, "cpt")
        for code in row['CPT_codes'].split('~'):
            ET.SubElement(cptNode, "code").text = code

        ET.SubElement(psNode, "hcpcs")
        
        doc = ET.tostring(root, method='xml', encoding="UTF-8")
        
        response = requests.post(target_url, data=doc, headers=login_details)
        response_data = json.loads(response.text)
        if type(response_data)==dict and 'error' in response_data.keys():
            error_results.append(response_data)
        else:
            api_results.append(response_data)
```

What do I need to change so that I can loop through the csv file and put the data into xml format to make my API call?

I've tested this code out in python and it seems to be working, but once I put my file HDFS it begins to fall over.

Comment: Maybe because the header is not read by the reader? Where do you get the error message?

Comment: @Stefan Once I start the `for loop`. How do do I specify the header?

Comment: @Stefan it is indeed reading the header of that file. Not sure how to handle this change.

Comment: This isn't Spark code. Removing tag.

Comment: Can you update the question to include the full error message (particularly including the line number)? The first thing to try is to guess what variable is mistakenly an `int`, and print it (or better, some parent of it).

Comment: If you want to skip the header, and `reader` is actually iterating over lines rather than characters in the file, then simply add `next(reader)` before the enumerate, or use a regular loop because you never use `i`

Comment: Also, is the variable `hdfs` coming from an import? Show us that, and link us the documentation.

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter `hdfs` is coming from an inport import `pydoop.hdfs as hdfs` here's the documentation [https://crs4.github.io/pydoop/api_docs/hdfs_api.html] and the `int` is falling over on the for loop

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (probably; I don't have this library installed) that `f.read()` is returning a [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) object. If you iterate over it (using `enumerate` for example) you'll be inspecting `int`s (one per character of the file, depending on context), not any kind of structured "row" objects.

Additional processing is necessary before you can start the loop you want to write.

Something like this *might* do what you want:

```py
import pydoop.hdfs as hdfs
from io import TextIOWrapper
from csv import DictReader

with hdfs.open("/user/ras.csv") as h,
     TextIOWrapper(h, *unknown_settings) as w,
     DictReader(w, *defaults_are_probably_ok) as dict_reader:
    for row in dict_reader:
        ...
```

Comment: What is unknown_settings and defaults_are_ok supposed to be?

Comment: Both functions/class-constructors take additional optional arguments; not knowing all of your situation, I'm not sure what you'll want to pass in there. The two modules are both in python's standard library; check the documentation for these particular functions and figure out if you need to over-ride any of the defaults.